# MenuItem Vertical alignment issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I am facing an issue with MenuItem that whenever I specify an access key, the header alignment is getting disrupted. Below is a sample image wherein I have specified "_New" for New menu item and bound it to New command. You can observe tha the Text "New" is align at bottom and shortcut key is aligned at top. Also for other menu items I have not specified any access key, so they have no issue.

[image: MenuItem]

Here is the XAML

```
<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Menu  Padding="0,5">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MnuTask" Header="Task">
                <MenuItem x:Name="MnuNew" Header="_New" Command="New"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="MnuSave" Header="Save" Command="Save"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="MnuDelete" Header="Delete" Command="Delete"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="MnuRefresh" Header="Reload Data" Command="{x:Static Local:MainWindow.RefreshDataCommand}" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="MnuHistory" Header="View Range History" Command="{x:Static Local:MainWindow.RangeHistoryCommand}" />
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="MnuExit" Header="Exit" Command="Close"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MnuView" Header="View">
                <MenuItem x:Name="MnuFind" Header="Find Formula"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
     </StackPanel>
```

Could any body let me know what's going on?

Comment: could you let us see your XAML code?

Comment: Sure. I have Updated question with XAML.

Comment: Sorry.. I posted old code. Updated new code.

Comment: I just created a sample window with that xaml (using a DockPanel as the root container) and the menu rendered fine - no indentation. Have you tried creating a "bare bones" reproduction of the issue?

Comment: Yeah. The XAML works fine in XamlPad. But my project is in VS2010 + .NET 3.5. There it is displaying improperly.

Comment: Have you created a stripped down Window in your VS project that is nothing back a window, dock panel, stack panel and this menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I had the below TextBlock Style present in Resources section of my window. Commenting those lines resolved the issue. (But now I need to apply TextBlock style explicitly using keys :( )

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,6,3,0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
</Style>
```